# intuition of null space dimension in application

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I know the dimension of null space $A$ is the number of the free variable of matrix $A$, I asked the lecturer about I got trouble identifying the dimension of an equation (given in general equation, pretty general, e.g line, surface, hyperplane) in space, and he reply I could just re-write it as matrix and then the dimension of its null space, that's the dimension of the equation, but I have no idea about the intuition of the process, why does the dimension of its null space will be the dimension of the object?

Appreciate for any comments and help

Comment: Sorry, but your question is incoherent. Can you review and edit it? What object are you talking about?

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you for your reply. I've re-edited it. Is that make more sense now?

Comment: Nope, it doesn’t. An object doesn’t have a null space.

Comment: The general solution to a linear system $Ax = b$, if it is non-empty, is a translate of the nullspace of $A$ (i.e. the whole set, picked up and shifted by a single vector; any one particular solution to $Ax = b$ will do). The nullspace of $A$ is a linear subspace, and translates of linear subspaces are known as "affine subspaces". Their dimension is usually defined in terms of the linear subspace being translated (though there is such a thing as affine independence). So, it's sort of "by definition" that the dimension of these solution sets matches the dimension of the nullspace of $A$.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thank you for your reply. I totally understand what you have written, but I am retrieving this question and re-thinking about why does the "equation(in form of a matrix)"  dimension will be the dimension of null space, but not the dimension of column space?